Transportation in Life Cycle Assessment
I am looking to model a supply chain and associate carbon footprint of a certain product. I am using EcoInvent database with SimaPro.
This product has ingredients that are transported from point A to point B, and are processed at point B after the delivery is made.
The delivery is done, for example, using 3.5-7.5 mt lorry, via road. Lets assume that 1 kg of the material is being transported from A to B. When i assign the lorry to this delivery, does this mean that the lorry is only transporting 1 kg of material? Or does it take into account some weighted average, such that, that 1 kg is being transported with other goods?
Also, as the weight of delivery increases, say, 1 to 50 to 100 kg, the associated GWP also increases. Is the underlying assumption based on the fact that more weight = more fuel consumption?
I have tried looking onto the web and the documentation but i could not understand this. Any advice would be helpful.
